# On the difference of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I have two questions, once I read:

> No matter the sequence you have, if you subtract the first element from the last, you get the same result as if you add up the difference between each element, take for example the following sequence:
>   $$1, 3, 4, 10$$ where $$10 - 1 = 9$$ now from **1** to **3** there's *2* steps, from **3** to **4** there's *1* step, from **4** to **10** there's *6* steps, if you add those steps you get $$2 + 1 + 6 = 9$$ The same number as before.

My question is, how does this work and why does it work? And my second question... I remember reading this somewhere on a book, but I cannot recall the book's name, any of you have a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just saying that$$a_n-a_1=(a_n-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+\cdots+(a_3-a_2)+(a_2-a_1).$$You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), for instance.

Comment: The article doesn't provide a whole answer (as far as I can see), could you expand on the topic a bit? I am new to telescoping series.

Comment: @PabloIvan What is there to explain? In the expression $(a_n-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+\cdots+(a_3-a_2)+(a_2-a_1)$, $-a_{n-1}$ cancels $a_{n-1}$, $-a_{n-2}$ cancels $a_{n-2}$, and so on. In the end, the only remaining terms are $a_n$ and $-a_1$. Isn't this a whole answer for you?

Comment: Oh, of course, I just got confused about the notation but now it is clear! Thanks, José!

Comment: @PabloIvan Then perhaps that you could mark my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Absolutely. Done!